# advanced custom fields true/false only works in front-page.?? not in innerpages why?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields

I have an ACF true or false based if the condition to show a section based on the mentioned code. it works correctly on the front page/homepage of WordPress. but it doesn't work in the inner pages, not getting the values of the field and I use this code in footer templates.

its a WordPress site with the latest version. and the code is in the footer template

```
<?php 
$show_company_info = get_field( "show_company_info", get_the_ID() );
if($show_company_info ): 
?>
<section class="company">
  <div class="container">

      <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'company-info-widget' ) ) : ?>
      <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'company-info-widget' ); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>

  </div>
</section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

if we checked the ACF true/fields condition in any page it will show the section otherwise not. but it actually works in homepage only

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have created a field in a Home Page.
So, to retrieve the home page field you need to do like this :

```
$frontpage_id = get_option( 'page_on_front' );
$show_company_info = get_field( "show_company_info", $frontpage_id  );

 if ( $show_company_info ) {
     //Your code 
 }
```

Comment: no. i added the fields in all pages and posts using the acf rules. and it is shown in all pages

Comment: Try to retrieve ID using `global $post;  $page_id = $post->ID; $show_company_info = get_field( "show_company_info", $page_id );`